# Calling a resource with absolute VS relative paths in php

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

Ooookay.

So, I have this annoying issue. I'm calling a css file within an php/html doc and I'm getting strange results - probably because I'm failing to understand something.

I've defined a few constants in my application (constants.php):

```
define("ROOT", dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("RESOURCES", ROOT . DS . "resources" . DS);
define("CSS", RESOURCES . "css" . DS );
```

My folder structure looks something like:
Localhost (development root folder. FYI: it is C:\Users\Kyle\SkyDrive\www) 
 Framework 
   library (folder)  
    constants.php (file)  
   resources (folder) 
    CSS (folder)
     wuxia-blue.css
   views (folder)
    Booking (folder)
     dashboard.php (file)

Now, in my dashboard.php file I'm linking the css folder as follows:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="">
```

Now comes the issue: when I use href="/framework/resources/css/wuxia-blue.css", the css pulls perfectly fine and all looks great. Only problem is, I want to pull it with something like:

```
href="<?php echo(CSS); ?>wuxia-blue.css"
```

That resolves to ***C:\Users\Kyle\SkyDrive\www\Framework\resources\css\wuxia-blue.css*** which is the correct path to the resource but when I use it, no CSS pulls through on the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your CSS constant contains the root.

You could just str_replace this though

```
href="<?php echo(str_replace(ROOT,"",CSS)); ?>wuxia-blue.css"
```

Comment: Hmm. That isn't working either. That causes a http request to the following link: /framework/booking/\resources\css\wuxia-blue.css

Comment: Hmmmm so using your idea I came up with the solution. I defined an additional constant called SUBROOT_REL and defined it as DS . "framework" . DS. I also changed the value of DS to "/" and then used str_replace(ROOT, SUBROOT_REL, CSS). Check mark for you.....